# How to create a new reactant Ammonium Dinitramide NH4[N(NO2)] in NASA CEA?

Tags: rockets, nasa, simulation

Ammonium Dinitramide(ADN) is a compound used as a green propellant for spacecraft propulsion applications. ADN-blends like LMP103S and FLP-106 are currently under development. However, performing a chemical equilibrium analysis and a subsequent rocket propulsion analysis using NASA CEA code has been giving me trouble.

How can I create ADN in NASA CEA?

Overall I need to have a mixture of 64% ADN(L), 23% H2O(L) and 13% CH3OH(L)

Comment: What is NASA CEA, for those of us who don't know?